# pulling a random number from a method in java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to make a program that will bring in two players then randomly choose who will go first. I'm trying to call in the random number from a method outside the main program. but the int beginner will only set two 0 when printed out.

main

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);
          point_system ps = new point_system();
          System.out.println("First player?");
          String player1 = kbr.next();
          hit_system p1 = new hit_system();
          System.out.println("Second player?");
          String player2 = kbr.next();
          hit_system p2 = new hit_system();
          ps.beginner();
          System.out.println(ps.beginner);
    if (ps.beginner == 1)
    {
          System.out.println(player1 + " goes first");
    }
    else if (ps.beginner == 2)
    {
       System.out.println(player2 + " goes first");
    }
    }
    }
```

pulling from method

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class point_system
    {
    public point_system()
    {
           beginner = 0;
    }
    public int beginner()
    {
           int beginner = (int )(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
           return beginner;
    }
           public int beginner;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have declared an instance variable `beginner` in your `point_system` class, set to `0`.  But then you declare another variable, local to the `beginner` method, also called `beginner` that performs the actual logic.

You refer to the `beginner` instance variable in your `main` method, and you never change the instance variable, only the local variable, in `point_system`, so that's why it's always `0`.

Instead, assign the result of the call to the `beginner` method to a variable.

```
int b = ps.beginner();
System.out.println(b);
if (b == 1)
```

Then you can remove the instance variable `beginner` from your `point_system` class.

Also, you will want to use `2` instead of `3` so that you don't accidentally return a `3` in `beginner`.

Answer (score 0):

`int beginner = (int )(Math.random() * 3 + 1);`

Use `Random` and `nextInt()`, instead. And, like others have said, you have scope issues with `beginner`.